# How to reset object value to null in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code

```
var data={};

data={stdId:"101"};
data={empId:"102"};
data={deptId:"201"};
```

I have a data object getting data from services with one key only. but key names are different like  `stdId` or `empId` ,etc.
I want to assign empty value to `stdId` or `empId` ,etc. like `data={stdId:""}` .
The key names are changed dynamically based on services.

Comment: How are you planning to use this kind data in your application even if you achieve just to make key value as null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you know the name of the property you could use:

```
data['stdId'] = '';
```

or

```
data.stdId = '';
```

If you do not know the property name, but you still want to keep the property names on the object you could use:

```
for(var prop in data) {
  if(data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    data[prop] = '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for..in` loop to iterate over data object using key.

```
for(var key in data){
  if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
     data[key] = '';
  }
}
```

#### Note: This will set every property of `data` object to `''`

Answer (score 0):

```
data.stdId = null;
```

or

```
data.stdId = '';
```

or

```
data = { stdId };
```

Have you tried those?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you won't know the name of the key in each object and there is only ever one. To solve your problem:

```
data[Object.keys(data)[0]] = ''
```

This will assign the value of the key to null.